# VIM map <C-q> to paste from system clipboard

Tags: windows, vim

I try to use following configuration:

```
vmap <C-q> c<ESC>"+p
imap <C-q> <ESC>"+pa
```

or

```
imap <C-q> "+gP
nmap <C-q> "+gP
```

but it seemed to have no effect and reported the "E73: tag stack empty" error.

Does it conflict with any plugins?

Comment: The first mappings worked for me.  Are you in visual mode or insert mode when you are pressing `<C-q>` and is there something in the `+` register?  You can `:reg +` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have set

```
 :set cb=unnamed
```

so that "+ gets set to the default (unnamed) register.  Then `c` in Visual mode will copy the changed text to the `+` register, right before you try to `p`ut it.  Try

```
:vmap <C-q> "_c<ESC>"+p
:help v_c
```

which sends the deleted text to the black-hole register (like /dev/null).

Your first :imap and your :nmap work for me.  The second :imap inserts a literal '"+gP'; was something lost in the formatting of your question?